# CLLocationManager don't stop

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

Dear fellow developers,

I am trying hard to find a solution for my problem regarfing CLLocationManager.

I use a CLLocationManager instance in my Application. If the user selects the Home button on the device or terminates the application I want the location services to stop.

Therefor I call `[self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];` - But this somehow doesn't work. The application enters the background and the small location arrow in the upper right corner of the status bar don't disappear. Even if I add `[self.locationManager release]` or `self.locationManager.delegate = nil;` - the location tracking don't stop :-/

It only disappears if I go to my device settings and switch off location services for the app. Whenever I switch back to location service enabled I immediately get a purple colored arrow next to the switch toggle and the icon reappears in the status bar.

My question is how can I turn off location services when the app enters the background or is terminated?

Thanks a lot in advance and have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do it the right way. When entering background, it's ok if some delegate methods are called for some seconds. That should stop.

Where do you stop the location updates ? Are you sure it is triggered ? If yes, are your delegate method called even if the visual indicators tell something else ?

Are you sure you don't trigger a method that reactivate the location update after you have stopped it (because for example you can receive some updates even after stopped).

Comment: Oh my it was my mistake. I overlooked the fact that I was monitoring a region. I thought when it says 'stop updating location' that the location framework really stops on all levels. A little bit misleading in my opinion...

When I stop the region monitoring and I send the application to the background than the upper right arrow disappears as in other applications like Maps etc. Thanks for your hint - otherwise I would search for a while for a solution... :-)

Answer (score 5):

Your location is disabled. The location service icon "meaning" has changed on iOS 5. Take a look at this question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27463/why-is-the-location-services-icon-always-present

I Quote the answer:

> It's a new feature in ios 5 called "region Monitoring"
>
> The reason it's active even if the app is closed is that this feature
>   runs in iOS 5 core and notifies all apps that are registered when they
>   have entered or left a specific geo-fence.
>
> Reminders does that when you use a location based reminder.
>
> Although the location icon appears at all time. This actually has very
>   minimal impact on the battery due to apple really optimizing this
>   feature by using cell and wifi mostly.

Your app is working ok. The system behaviour is the one who changed.

Answer (score 1):

For instance if you started monitoring a significant location change, then you should unsubscribe from it with the corresponding pair method. If you are using region enter, then until you unsubscribe, the system will notify your delegates.